# Подскажите, как правильно создать SQL таблицу?

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, codeigniter, таблицы

Есть вот такой файл.
Подскажите, как правильно создать и заполнить таблицу "guest"?
И какие значения где потом выставить? (varchar, int и т.д.)
Только начинаю, прошу не кидаться камнями)
Заранее огромное спасибо!

```html
<?php

/**
 * Хуки выполняются на каждой странице
 */
class App
{
  private $CI;

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->CI = &get_instance();
  }

  /* конфиги из базы */
  public function conf()
  {
    $settings = $this->CI->db->get('settings')->result();
    foreach ($settings as $s) {
      $this->CI->config->set_item($s->item_key, $s->val);
    }
    /* города */
    $cities = $this->CI->db->get('cities')->result();
    $this->CI->config->set_item('cities', $cities);


    /* список страниц для сайта */
    $pages = $this->CI->db->select('id, title')->order_by('ord')->get('pages')->result();
    $this->CI->config->set_item('menu', $pages);

    /* Способы оплаты  */
    $result = $this->CI->db->get('pay_methods')->result();
    $pay_methods = array();
    foreach ($result as $p) {
      $pay_methods[$p->system][$p->id] = $p;
    }
    if ($pay_methods) $this->CI->config->set_item('pay_methods', $pay_methods);

    /* доступные опера */
    $now_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time()-60);
    $oper = $this->CI->db->select('*')->where('last_visit > ', $now_date)->order_by('last_visit', 'DESC')->limit(1)->get('users')->row();
    $this->CI->config->set_item('oper_online', $oper);
  }

  function admin()
  {
    /* для админки */
    if ($this->CI->router->directory == 'admin/') {
      if (!$this->CI->session->user) redirect('/auth/login');
      if ($this->CI->session->user->role == 2 && $this->CI->router->class != 'products') {
        redirect('/admin/products');
      }

    }
  }

  function guest()
  {

    if($this->CI->router->class == 'cron') return 0;

    if ($this->CI->agent->is_browser())
    {
      $agent = $this->CI->agent->browser().' '.$this->CI->agent->version();
    }
    elseif ($this->CI->agent->is_robot())
    {
      $agent = $this->CI->agent->robot();
    }
    elseif ($this->CI->agent->is_mobile())
    {
      $agent = $this->CI->agent->mobile();
    }
    else
    {
      $agent = $this->CI->agent->agent_string();
    }



    $guest = $this->CI->input->cookie('guest');
    $date_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    if ($guest) {
      settype($guest, 'int');
      $guest = $this->CI->db->get_where('guest', array('id' => $guest))->row();
      $guest->last_visit = $date_time;
      $guest->ip = $this->CI->input->ip_address();
      $guest->agent = $agent;

      if($this->CI->session->user){
        $guest->full_name = $this->CI->session->user->full_name;
        $this->CI->db->update('users', array('last_visit' => $date_time), array('id' => $this->CI->session->user->id ) );
      }

      $this->CI->db->update('guest', $guest, array('id' => $guest->id ) );
    } else {
      $guest = array(
        'full_name' => 'Гость',
        'ip' => $this->CI->input->ip_address(),
        'last_visit' => $date_time,
        'agent' => $agent
      );

      $this->CI->db->insert('guest',$guest);
      $guest = $this->CI->db->insert_id();
      $this->CI->db->update('guest', array('full_name' => 'Гость #'.$guest), array('id' => $guest ) );
      $cookie = array(
        'name'   => 'guest',
        'value'  => $guest,
        'expire' => 32000000,
        'domain' => $this->CI->input->server('SERVER_NAME'),
        'path'   => '/'
      );
      $this->CI->input->set_cookie($cookie);
    }

    $this->CI->config->set_item('guest', $guest);

  }

}
```

Comment: А какие поля то должны быть? Из тех что представлены: id - INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT, full_name - VARCHAR(255), ip - VARCHAR(15), last_visit - DATE или INT(11), в зависимости от того как CI даты хранит и обрабатывает, agent - VARCHAR(255). НО это явно не все поля.

Comment: Мне вот и интересно какие поля должны быть, и какие могут быть еще в таблице guest? Файл в принципе только этот отвечает.